# Getting a weird cast exception : javax.mail.session cannot be cast to javax.mail.session

Tags: jboss5.x, apache-commons-email

I am trying to use `apche-commons-email` API for sending an email, in my java web application. I have configured the `jboss5 mail-service.xml` to send emails from `Gmail` id. But I am getting the error

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
                 javax.mail.Session cannot be cast to javax.mail.Session
```

when executing the line

```
Session mailSession = (Session) ictx.lookup("java:/Mail");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only see this as a custom class loader loading a `javax.mail.Session` class along with the original `javax.mail.Session` object !

But when attempting to cast an object of the first class to an instance of the second, an exception occurs because both objects don't match (i.e. method names, member variables..etc)

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879929/897041) and other answers for the same question.