# Java Libraries Conflicts

Tags: java, jar

I am using Stanford POSTagger in my project and imported the tagger .jar
and it worked just fine but the problem i encountered when i tried to add Stanford NER_Recognizer .jar file to my project Both of the jars have the same namespace edu.stanford.nlp but there are classes in the NER .jar not present in the POStagger.jar

So I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: strictGoodCoNLL
>       at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.featuresCpC(NERFeatureFactory.java:1710) "
>   this is because the pos tagger .jar has edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils class 
>   which is also present in the NER .jar

So, how can I choose that I want the second class not the first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to use two java classes with same name and same package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879652/possible-to-use-two-java-classes-with-same-name-and-same-package)

Comment: there r no useful answer i can use in that question how could i call a classloader and not make the same conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming second jar should always override the first one something like this should suffice.

```
java -classpath  NER_Recognizer.jar;tagger.jar
```

from Java 8 [Class Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) page

> Specification Order
>
> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is
>   important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the
>   directories in the order they appear in the class path variable. In
>   the previous example, the Java interpreter will first look for a
>   needed class in the directory C:\java\MyClasses. Only when it does not
>   find a class with the proper name in that directory will the
>   interpreter look in the C:\java\OtherClasses directory.

Comment: The issue is not that the class cannot be found, it's that the class can be found twice. I don't think this addresses the issue because there will still be a namespace collision.

Comment: @NonSecwitter In case of collision the order in which dependencies are mentioned in the classpath will take precedence, which I think should solve the problem.

Comment: @AjayGeorge how could i add this insruction i am using Netbeans so where could i put it

Comment: @Firas252 You just need to make sure NER_Recognizer.jar is the first entry in the classpath after which tagger.jar is mentioned. [How to set classpaths in Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans)

Comment: you where right its by rearranging them as you said it works so i have to choose the priority of the .jars thanks @AjayGeorge