# Two different .jar with same Package name and same Class name. How to get the one?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my project I have standard java system library with rt.jar that have class.

```
package javax.xml;

public final class XMLConstants {

    private XMLConstants() {
    }

    public static final String NULL_NS_URI = "";
    public static final String DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX = "";
    ...
}
```

And also included is stax-api-1.0.jar with class

```
package javax.xml;

public class XMLConstants {
    public static final String DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX = "";
    public static final String XML_NS_PREFIX = "xml";
    public static final String XML_NS_URI = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace";
    public static final String XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE = "xmlns";
    public static final String XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE_NS_URI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/";
}
```

And in third class I need to get NULL_NS_URI that looks like this

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;

public myClass(){

    doSomethin() {
        ...
        XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI
        ...
    }
}
```

It gives error

```
NULL_NS_URI cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

And when I ctrl + click on XMLConstants in myClass eclipse takes me to class stax-api.jar.
When I do same thing on colleague machine eclipse take him to rt.jar with no error because NULL_NS_URI is defined in that class.

Comment: Removing `stax-api-1.0.jar` from your dependencies would solve your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879652/possible-to-use-two-java-classes-with-same-name-and-same-package

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check your build class path order. If the `rt.jar` resides above the `stax-api-1.0.jar`, the problem should get resolved. Because, while compilation, the compiler looks up the jars in the build class path order.

Comment: This works. I accepted answer but cant upvote it says i need more reputation.

Comment: Good to know that it worked. :) Thanks for accepting.. You can upvote later when you get more reputation.. :D

Comment: @ArkaGhosh Any idea, at run time which class file Java would consider for execution