# Java: What happens when I create the same package as API

Tags: java

I'm curious what would happen if I create the exact same package that exists in an API that the project has (e.g. `java.util` from core Java API). Would the compiler give me an error or something?

If the compiler allows this, what would happen if I create a class with a name that the original API has?

Also, does that mean that package-private fields and methods are accessible if the compiler doesn't complain?

Comment: Maybe you could start by trying it out and reporting at least partial results here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to use two java classes with same name and same package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879652/possible-to-use-two-java-classes-with-same-name-and-same-package)

Comment: @JorgeCampos That question seems more for adding 2 API with conflicting package/name to the project. It may be closely related but I don't think these two questions are similar enough.

Answer (score 3):

I was curious enough that I did my own testing. I created `java.util.concurrent` and created a Test class with this method:

```
public static Object getResult(CompletableFuture<?> cf) {
    return cf.result;
}
```

Then I called it somewhere else in a `main` method. There is no compile error. Running that causes this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited
>   package name: java.util.concurrent    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:662)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)

So, it does seem like it has to do with classloader... or so I thought... Until I took a look at `ClassLoader.preDefineClass()`:

```
// Note:  Checking logic in java.lang.invoke.MemberName.checkForTypeAlias
// relies on the fact that spoofing is impossible if a class has a name
// of the form "java.*"
if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
    throw new SecurityException
        ("Prohibited package name: " +
         name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
}
```

So, it's stopping me because Java wants to protect all the packages starting with `java`!

I went and tried something else. I added `javafx.scene` package and another Test class with this method:

```
public static boolean getBoundsChange(Node n) {
    return n.boundsChanged;
}
```

Again, there is no compile errors, but it throws this at runtime:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field
>   javafx.scene.Node.boundsChanged from class javafx.scene.TestNode  at
>   javafx.scene.TestNode.getBoundsChange(TestNode.java:7)    at
>   testFX.start(testFX.java:29)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     ... 1 more

Seems like Java does protect against these, but does so only at runtime.

I created another interface in `javafx.scene` and just let it extend `Consumer<T>`. I can use it just like the original `Consumer<T>`, so there is nothing stopping me from using that package for my new classes.

Comment: It might be VM dependent, I've created java.util.concurrent package in my Android project and it runs fine.

Comment: @urgentx You mean you could call the package-private method/field and do whatever it's supposed to do, and not get an exception or error?

Comment: Nope, if I re-declare an already existing util.concurrent class it will not import it, but will still compile. If I create a class Test in java.util.concurrent and I can use it elsewhere without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will be blocked by the class loader if the package name is prohibited, as in the case of `java`, or if you're trying to break into a package that is sealed in the JAR file it is distributed in.

Comment: Does the `IllegalAccessError` has to do with class loader?

Comment: @Jai No, the `ClassLoader` isn't running at that point. I don't know the mechanism for the `IllegalAccessException` you got.

Answer (score -1):

Java packages are backed by folders on the file system, therefore you cannot create a copy of a package as it would just be the same folder.

There is nothing stopping you from creating a java.util package in your own project and using that. It would be a unique package name, and have nothing to do with the Java API.

Comment: He didn't say anything about classes though. I understood that the OP was more interested in taking a look at the package-visible stuff.

Comment: Java packages can be in jar files too so you could very well have conflicts by having different jar files with the same packages and class.

Comment: This is exactly what he has done, and it has failed. You cannot create classes in a `java.*` package. The JVM will not load them.

Comment: @EJP It seems to be VM/build tool dependent, I had no issues doing that in an Android project.