# if two libraries have classes that have the same class& package name for their internal use

Tags: java, package, classpath, classloader, classname

I have two jars that have the same package structure. 
And they have a class that have the same name. 
like..

```
lib1.jar
   - A.class
   - Same.class
lib2.jar
   - B.class
   - Same.class
```

Actually, I don't use Same.class but it is used by class A and B

Then, what happened?

If lib1.jar is loaded first, only Same.class in lib1.jar is used for both A.class and B.class?

or A & B will use different Same.class in their own jar?

Comment: Question: Are the _package_ names also identical?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Yes, they have the same package structure, and I cannot change them.

Comment: Yes, you should never build your jars this way.  The classloader will only load one class per fully-qualified name.

Comment: If you ever make your code modular (Java 9+) then what you're describing will be impossible because split-packages are not allowed by the module system.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't any special `Class loader` , which loads different classes at run time, the class loaded first will be used in both the places. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879652/possible-to-use-two-java-classes-with-same-name-and-same-package) for more info.