# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gl

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am new using the libgdx library.  I have a desktop application and getting this error after running my app.

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gl
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gl
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setDisplayMode(LwjglGraphics.java:360)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:155)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:122)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)

I have no idea to fix it. My classpath includes **libgdx-0.9.8** version jars.

Comment: Possible reasons behind error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686753/nosuchfielderror-java). So you can try clean/rebuild or you might have different versions of compile/runtime jars.

Comment: You're also using a pretty old version of Libgdx, why not use [1.1.0](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3451)?

Comment: Thanks David. I replaced with newer version of jars.