# Java mail runnable jar not running

Tags: java, eclipse, email, executable-jar

I am developing a monitoring program, which sends periodic emails.
Every thing went fine until I tried to make it a runnable jar. 
The mailing part is working fine in eclipse and I am able to send email. But as soon as I make it a runnable jar the program never sends email.

What am I doing wrong?

```
package mailing;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
public class TestEmail
{
void addRecipients(Message.RecipientType type,  Address[] addresses)throws MessagingException
    {

    }
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {   
        final int port = 465;
        final String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        final String from = "*****@gmail.com";
        final String to = "********@gmail.com";
         boolean auth = true;
        final String username = "*******@gmail.com";
        final String password = "**********";

    boolean debug = true;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");

    Authenticator authenticator = null;

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            @Override
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return pa;
            }

        };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
    session.setDebug(debug);


    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to.toString())};
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        String subject="- Job Alert -";
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        String body="Hello you got a new mail";
        message.setText(body);
        Transport.send(message);

    }


}
```

This is eclipse console when running from eclipse.
Notice : closing connection in the end.
This code sends email.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP fk4sm25070066pab.23 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO jason-DesktopPC1
250-mx.google.com at your service, [49.204.224.235]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Y2hlcnkwMTJAZ21haWwuY29t
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
VGFuaXRhbmkwMTI=
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<chery012@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK fk4sm25070066pab.23 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<avinandan012@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK fk4sm25070066pab.23 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   avinandan012@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead fk4sm25070066pab.23 - gsmtp
Date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 16:17:57 +0530 (IST)
From: chery012@gmail.com
To: avinandan012@gmail.com
Message-ID: <399262.0.1403174877546.JavaMail.example@gmail.com>
Subject: - Job Alert -
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello you got a new mail
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1403174885 fk4sm25070066pab.23 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection fk4sm25070066pab.23 - gsmtp
```

This is from Win7 cmd using > java -jar EmailTest.jar
Notice: The programme never quits. No closing connection.
This jar does not sends email.

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ih6sm8024528pbc.22 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO jason-DesktopPC1
250-mx.google.com at your service, [49.204.224.235]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Y2hlcnkwMTJAZ21haWwuY29t
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
VGFuaXRhbmkwMTI=
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<chery012@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK ih6sm8024528pbc.22 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<avinandan012@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK ih6sm8024528pbc.22 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   avinandan012@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead ih6sm8024528pbc.22 - gsmtp
Date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 16:30:51 +0530 (IST)
From: chery012@gmail.com
To: avinandan012@gmail.com
Message-ID: <32535959.01403175651787.JavaMail.example@gmail.com>
Subject: - Job Alert -
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello you got a new mailQUIT
```

Comment: do yourself a favour - delete the emailaddress-password combo from your post.

Comment: ...and change the password asap

Comment: thank you both. Was very distracted didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, just try the code :

```
public boolean sendMail(final String senderEmail, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String bccEmail) {

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    try {

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail));
        if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail));
        }
        if(bccEmail.length() > 0){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bccEmail));
        }
        message.setSubject(this.subject);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        message.setText(this.textMessage, "utf-8");

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");

        t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", senderEmail, password);
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();

        System.out.println("Message sent successfully to '" + recipientEmail + "; " + ccEmail + "'.");

        return true;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("Message not sent to '" + recipientEmail + "; " + ccEmail + "'.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport class? This code too works in the IDE but throwing an exception when packed as runnable jar

Comment: yes I am using [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn)

Comment: C:\Users\jason\Desktop>java -jar EmailTest1.jar   
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: atBOL  
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPOutputStream.ensureAtBOL(SMTPOutputStream.java:107)   
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1472)     
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:738)   
    at mailing.TestEmail.sendMail(TestEmail.java:49)          
    at mailing.TestEmail.main(TestEmail.java:68)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6686792/2764279) may-be the solution for your problem.

Comment: problem solved! manually compiling files and packaging the libraries into the jar solved it. Don't know what went wrong.  Strange

Comment: you have to put all your libraries in directory `lib` with your jar file to use them.