# NoSuchFieldError: MARGIN using ZXing library

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I'm using ZXing library to generate QR codes, and I'm trying to set `MARGIN` property to 1 by this way:

```
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 1); // java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MARGIN
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.Q);

QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix byteMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(contents, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 100, 100, hintMap);
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MARGIN`. I'm using 2.3.0 version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also examined EncodeHintType.class with Eclipse, and MARGIN property is there! I don't understand what's happening.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6686792/2900829), I discovered that I had installed on Tomcat server two different versions of this library: `core-2.0` and `core-2.3.0`. My code was using at runtime 2.0 version instead of 2.3.0.

I removed `core-2.0.jar` from Tomcat, and now it's working! :)