# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError :Companion

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, nosuchfieldexception, statsig

I am using Statsig Library for A/B testing in my JDK17 project.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.statsig</groupId>
  <artifactId>serversdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.statsig</groupId>
  <artifactId>ip3country</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

While Debugging the project, I am facing the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
at com.statsig.sdk.ErrorBoundary.<clinit>(ErrorBoundary.kt:15)
at com.statsig.sdk.StatsigServerImpl.<init>(StatsigServer.kt:178)
at com.statsig.sdk.StatsigServer$Companion.create(StatsigServer.kt:161)
at com.statsig.sdk.Statsig$Companion.initializeAsync(Statsig.kt:341)
at com.statsig.sdk.Statsig.initializeAsync(Statsig.kt)
at com.ekart.abservice.resources.statsig.StatsigServiceImpl.<init>(StatsigServiceImpl.java:63)
at com.ekart.abservice.resources.statsig.StatsigSDK.init(StatsigSDK.java:16)
at com.ekart.abservice.resources.ABService.initializeStatsigSDKWithRetries(ABService.java:84)
at com.ekart.abservice.resources.ABService.initialize(ABService.java:69)
at com.ekart.abservice.resources.ABService.initialize(ABService.java:45)
at com.cs.platform.ab.AbServiceWrapper.initAbServiceWrapper(AbServiceWrapper.java:35)
at com.cs.platform.PlatformApplication.initialiseABService(PlatformApplication.java:263)
at com.cs.platform.PlatformApplication.run(PlatformApplication.java:238)
at com.cs.platform.PlatformApplication.run(PlatformApplication.java:80)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
at com.cs.platform.PlatformApplication.main(PlatformApplication.java:113)
```

Could you please help me find the issue.

Comment: Please check if the problem is reproduced if you launch the project from the command line outside of the IntelliJ IDEA. Possible direction for debugging this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/6686792/12844632

Comment: Mismatch of versions in Pom.xml perhaps?

Comment: What does your initialization code look like? (Remove your server key)

Comment: At this point, v1.2.3 is a fairly outdated version, give it a shot with v1.10.1 and let us know if you still run into issues