# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: chunkSize is visible when trying to run sample program of Apache Arrow

Tags: java, parquet, apache-arrow

When trying to run the first sample program from Apache arrow website for Java, No such field error  for chunkSize is visible in the line `this.chunkSize = this.directArenas[0].chunkSize;`

The full error is,

```
2023-12-29T10:53:04.840+05:30 ERROR 2776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: chunkSize] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: chunkSize
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL$InnerAllocator.<init>(PooledByteBufAllocatorL.java:153) ~[arrow-memory-netty-14.0.2.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL.<init>(PooledByteBufAllocatorL.java:49) ~[arrow-memory-netty-14.0.2.jar!/:4.1.104.Final]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.NettyAllocationManager.<clinit>(NettyAllocationManager.java:51) ~[arrow-memory-netty-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.DefaultAllocationManagerFactory.<clinit>(DefaultAllocationManagerFactory.java:26) ~[arrow-memory-netty-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.DefaultAllocationManagerOption.getFactory(DefaultAllocationManagerOption.java:108) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.DefaultAllocationManagerOption.getDefaultAllocationManagerFactory(DefaultAllocationManagerOption.java:98) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator$Config.getAllocationManagerFactory(BaseAllocator.java:773) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig.access$801(ImmutableConfig.java:24) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig$InitShim.getAllocationManagerFactory(ImmutableConfig.java:83) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig.<init>(ImmutableConfig.java:47) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig.<init>(ImmutableConfig.java:24) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.ImmutableConfig$Builder.build(ImmutableConfig.java:485) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at org.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator.<clinit>(BaseAllocator.java:62) ~[arrow-memory-core-14.0.2.jar!/:14.0.2]
        at com.apache.arrow.arrowExample.service.ArrowModule1.ArrowModule1.arrowMethod(ArrowModule1.java:13) ~[!/:na]
        at com.apache.arrow.arrowExample.controller.FilePathController.readFile(FilePathController.java:38) ~[!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:262) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar!/:6.1.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Trying to run the getting started Apache arrow program from the site https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/quickstartguide.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NoSuchFieldError Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686753/nosuchfielderror-java)

Comment: You may run a dependency tree to identify classpath conflicts, there are likely some.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when updated Spring Boot version of my app to `3.1.7`. I tried to even update arrow to latest version `14.0.2` with the same outcome.

The problem is following:

- arrow `14.0.2` is developed against netty `4.1.96.Final` ([see in arrow repository](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/maint-14.0.2/java/pom.xml#L36C28-L36C40))
- Spring Boot `3.1.7` brings netty `4.1.104.Final` (see [SB dependencies](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.1.7/spring-boot-dependencies-3.1.7.pom))

  - in that version the class `io.netty.buffer.PoolArena` really does not contain field referenced by Arrow.

I have solved it for now by degrading the netty version in my SB application to `4.1.96.Final` by doing following in my `gradle.build.kts`:

```
// Spring Boot 3.1.7 uses netty.version 4.1.104.Final which seems incompatible with arrow-memory-netty 14.0.2
// that internally depends on netty.version 4.1.96.Final. When used together with netty 4.1.104.Final,
// it ends up on missing field chunkSize that is being called when initializing RootAllocator.
//
// It seems that arrow of version 15.x uses netty 4.1.105.Final internally, but it is not yet released in maven.
// When we update arrow to that version, please try it with netty version from Spring Boot.
ext["netty.version"] = "4.1.96.Final"
```

As specified in the comment above, when there is arrow version `15.x.x` released (I saw that version in their github but not yet in central maven) we should try to remove the netty version override and it will probably work again by default.